# .Net sample app demonstrating use of floating/dockable panel

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, monodevelop

I am looking tyo write my first .Net application, coming from a *nix background.

My application will have dockable/floating panels and I am looking for a sample application to get me started. In an ideal world, I would like to develop using monodevelop, but the *nix GUI tools are atrocious, so it looks like I'll have to settle for VisualStudio (and thus possibly limit the app to Windows).

The sample app may be written in either C# or VB.Net (I am familiar with both languages).

I will be grateful for any links that point me in the right direction in devloping the GUI for such an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below link for a demonstration:

http://avalondock.codeplex.com/

You may have to look at using WPF for this if you want to be as effective as possible. Also, in the right envrionments you can compile both windows and windows mobile.

http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/

Was programmed using this and it has the relevant panels and documentation. Please try this and refer back to me if you can't use WPF :)

Comment: This looks exactly like what I'm looking for!. However, its not clear how I should use the dll. Do you have a "Hello World" project that I can take a look at to see how to use dll etc to create an app with the dockable/floating panels etc?

Comment: If you got to downloads, there should be an "AvalonDock_Samples.zip" availible to download - this will do more than the "Hello World" you want, it will show you full working examples. Hope this has helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use GTK as your user interface to maintain portability. Regarding docking a quick search reveales [A sample on github](https://github.com/amolenaar/MonoDockingWidget)